# Is it possible let chroot jails share directories(read-only) outside the jail?

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization, chroot

I have muliple chroot jails, I want them to share 
some directories, currently I have to copy these directories into
jails which I think is not elegant. The directories are read-only, like '/usr/bin'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the new bind mounts support to make identical directory structures available through multiple paths.

```
mount --bind /usr/bin /path/to/chroot/jail/usr/bin
mount -o remount,ro /path/to/chroot/jail/usr/bin
```

For more details, see `mount(8)`.

You can get *really* clever with mounting on Linux systems these days; for more details, see the Linux kernel source file [`Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt?id=HEAD).

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 this makes the source directory (not only the mounted one) also read only :/

Comment: acoording to http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128388/11869 it neets to be 1. `mount SRC DST -o bind` 2. `mount DST -o remount,ro,bind`

Answer (score 2):

try

```
mount /outside /inside -o bind
```